# How to use Case When with Between in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I want to retrieve the ROLE from the table on the basis of SOA_VALUE. ie if the SOA_VALUE is in between 100 and 500 then ROLE should be RSM. If SOA_VALUE is more than 500 then ROLE should be TMM. The SOA_VALUE is coming from front end.

```
ROLE    CHANNEL    PLG     TRANTYPE     SOA_VALUE
ASM       GT       DETS    TRANSFER     0    
RSM       GT       DETS    TRANSFER     100  
TMM       GT       DETS    TRANSFER     500
```

Ex: If the SOA_VALUE is 122,then role should come as RSM.

Please give me any suggestion/example query to retrieve the Role.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
 SELECT CHANNEL,PLG,TRANTYPE,SOA_VALUE
    FROM TABLE_X          
      WHERE ROLE = (CASE 
    WHEN (120 >= 100 AND 120 <=500) THEN 'RSM'
    WHEN 120 > 500 THEN 'TMM'
    ELSE NULL
                   end)
```

Replace 120 with the string value of the SOA_VALUE above.

Demo:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72d7f/3

Comment: +1 for explicitly covering off the case where SOA_VALUE < 100. Hope the OP also tests for null values

Comment: @Rajaganesh The above query ll give records along with Role according to the Soa_Value available in the table. As I hv written above, my requirement is little bit different..I am getting the SOA_VALUE from the user front end (html text box)...I need to choose the appropriate Role from the SOA_Master Table.

Comment: @Rajaganesh Please go through below scenario...Suppose I got 122 from the front end along with channel/plg/trantype, then in the soa_master I need to check: (122 > 0 & 122 <= 100) then ASM : (122 > 100 & 122 <=500) then RSM : (122 >500) then TMM. The max & min values (0,100,500) should be retrieved on the basis of role, channel,plg,trantype from the same table...

Comment: Sure. I am trying this. Let me get you an answer!

Comment: @Rajaganesh Thanks for your help...It resolved my problem...Actually I am looking for somthing like this...    SELECT ROLE FROM TABLE_X WHERE ROLE = (CASE 
        WHEN (130 >= (select SOA_VALUE from table_x where Role='RSM') AND 130 <=(select SOA_VALUE from table_x where Role='TMM')) THEN 'RSM'
        WHEN 130 > (select SOA_VALUE from table_x where Role='TMM') THEN 'TMM'
        ELSE 'ASM'  end)

Comment: @mustaccio Did you see the reply from OP? Can you please revert?

Comment: @Manu You are welcome. Can you please acknowledge this helped you by voting?

Comment: While this hardcoding works, it's something that would need to be updated every time a new entry was added to the table.  Functionally, this isn't much different than just embedding it in application code.  Likely, a query that can dynamically discover the correct value would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
with t(input_soa_value) as (values 121) -- simulates input value
select role from table_x where soa_value = (
  select max(soa_value) from table_x, t where soa_value < input_soa_value
)
```

Comment: Except that I have a feeling there will be cases when the entire row should be retrieved.  But something along these lines, yes.  (oh, and in the future, it's considered polite to include an example run via something like sqlFiddle).